# What does $g(x,y)=x+y^2$ look like?

Tags: general-topology, functions, graphing-functions

What does $g(x,y)=x+y^2$? I know it'd be a circle if the $x$ was squared, but I'm not entirely sure what this one would be? A parabola? I've never seen this written in this form.

Comment: The graph of that would be a surface in $3-$space.  Did you maybe mean $x+y^2=c$ for some constant $c$?  That's a parabola.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a parabolla for any given value of $z$ where $z=x+y^2$
[image]